# Run Console to TTY dynamically on LINUX

Tags: linux, console, arm9

We have embebed linux on ARM9 board which is connected to another board by serial line TTY1, no other way to communicate with the ARM9 board (no ethernet no usb), in our normal state application ARM9 board exchange datas with the other board on TTY1. In maintenance mode we want to run console on the ARM9 linux board, so our idea was :

- Send special command to our software
- Our software DO SOMETHINGS to prepare console activation on TTY1 for next reboot
- Programatically reboot software
- NOW in console mode to TTY1
- Change whathever we need
- Ask to normal reboot and run our normal software

We need some help on step 2, what we can write somewhere or which command we can programatically run to tell linux to reboot on console mode to TTY1 ?

Answer (score 1):

tty1 would normally be a virtual terminal - perhaps ttyS0 or ttyS1?

There are basically two things that need to be done - getting the kernel to output to the serial connection during boot, and running a terminal program on the serial line.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Working_with_the_serial_console

gives some good clues on how to set things up, but you'll have to adapt them for your setup.